# meaning of "you heard it here first"

Tags: meaning

Tried googling the phrase but what I got was a bunch of articles using this phrase 
as the title instead of something defining the meaning of the phrase.

Is it something used by the media to indicate they are the first one to report it?

Comment: What part of "you heard it here first" is difficult to understand?

Comment: __scoop__ or __exclusive__ comes to mind

Comment: The phrase is sometimes used as a generic boast by the media outlet, somewhat like a catch phrase.  When used as a title, it's just a teaser, implying that what's in the story to follow is something you haven't yet heard anywhere else (they're allowed to exaggerate, it isn't really a guarantee).  Online, that's an example of "click bait".

Comment: It's an old radio/TV news "catch phrase".  Goes back to the 60s at least, likely a decade or two before that.

Comment: The race to be first to report something is one of the dumbest aspects of an aggressive, competitive, and free press. What matters is the comprehensiveness and accuracy of the news, not whether one outlet reported it an hour before another outlet. Nevertheless "you heard it here first" encapsulates the foolish preoccupation with scooping everyone else that remains a brass ring in throughout the news media.  It reminds me of the tagline that an early rock'n'roll-focused radio station had: "We start 'em; the others chart 'em."